# Dynamic creation of instances of a component

Tags: redhawksdr

I am using REDHAWK 1.9 on CentOS 6.3 32 bit...

I have a REDHAWK component that takes in one data stream. The waveform may want to have more than one instance of the class depending upon the data. Is it possible to do the following:

1. Create an instance of a component on the fly when the waveform is running?
2. Create dynamic connections between components when the waveform is running?

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan, I'm not sure I totally understand your question but let me try an answer and you can clarify if I'm misunderstanding.  It sounds like you want to have a waveform running, and depending on what the waveform does to the data flowing into it, launch more waveforms to perform other tasks on the data.  Is that correct?

Dynamic launching of waveforms based on the meeting of certain conditions is not included natively with REDHAWK.  However, it would be possible to create a component to do this and include it in one of your waveforms.

When stringing together multiple waveforms, make sure the connecting ports are configured as external ports.

Comment: I am thinking of creating components inside one waveform. So within one waveform creating instances of components and their corresponding connections dynamically.

Comment: No, you cannot dynamically add/create components inside an existing waveform or dynamically add/create/change connections.  You could either build a component to dynamically launch waveforms that handle certain conditions, or possibly include some sort of metadata with the data stream to help route the data through a selection of existing connections depending on certain conditions.  It's hard to be more specific without knowing more about what you're trying to do.